# Full Width Responsive Video Website Header With Buttons & Text

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, vimeo

I have been trying to recreate something like the video header video on this website. I love the fast load time with vimeo links too.

[Story Brand Video Header](https://storybrand.com/workshop/)

I have been at this all day. I can't seem to find the right combination of HTML, JS, & CSS to get this to work. Every way I have tried has either been full screen or leaves gaps on the sides. Also, many examples are not responsive. Please help!

HTML

```
<section id="big-video">
      <div class="video-box">
        <video data-id="2" muted="" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop">
          <source src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/123432922.hd.mp4? s=dabc3899c0a02b05a3e16a02d0d81758" type="video/mp4">
          <source src="http://player.vimeo.com/external/123432922.hd.mp4?s=dabc3899c0a02b05a3e16a02d0d81758.webm" type="video/webm">
        </video>
     </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
#big-video {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

The javascprit I tried to use was from https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-video-lightbox/

Thanks!
Kyle H

Edit - Added code

Comment: Since you are trying to recreate something, you need to share your recreated work. A minimum amount of work needs to be presented for others to look and build upon or fix. Do not expect others to write something from scratch for you

Comment: I added the code I was trying to get working.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a vimeo vid, this should do the trick. But only vimeo plus and pro accounts allow the background vids without buttons.

For the src in your Vimeo iframe, include `background=1` and `autoplay=1`. Including `"muted=1"` will allow autoplay for mobile devices. e.g.
`src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?background=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&muted=1"`

Adjust the css below as needed for video height. I believe the magic bullet in this situation is `object-fit`

```
    <section><div class="header-video" style="opacity: 1;">
        <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?background=1&api=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&muted=1&player_id=vvimeoVid" width="1920" height="1080" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div></section>

.header-video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.header-video iframe {
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    /* height based on 1920x1080 ratio */
    height: calc(100vw * 0.5625);
}
```

If you want to include custom js to mute/unmute, play/pause, etc. There's the vimeo API. I saw there's currently a bug in the Vimeo player.js API that makes it hard for videos to play in iOS right now.

I had better luck using the jQuery API. You can find that one here: https://github.com/jrue/Vimeo-jQuery-API

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/potatrick/pen/xWBqVe)

Comment: This is pretty awesome :) I am having a bit of trouble with this sticking to the bottom of the page though. I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Duh, forgot to include the js. Take a look at this. https://codepen.io/potatrick/pen/xWBqVe

Comment: This is awesome :) Perfect Solution

Comment: Please mark it as the answer if you found it helpful. Thanks!

Comment: `object-fit` doesn't work in IE or Edge on Video.  You can however vote to change that here:
https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-microsoft-edge-developer/suggestions/32011258-object-fit-and-object-position-for-all-media-eleme